# When loading a web widget through async scripts, should i load it in the head or should i load it in the footer?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

Currently it's advised to load `<script>` tags as close as possible to `</body>` closing tag.

I'm creating a web widget ( something similar to the like button of Facebook ) and i was wondering if this is the same case.

```
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/?ai1ec_requirejs_widget"></script>
```

After all this script will load a really tiny script which in turn will bring in everything that's needed for my widget through require.js, wouldn't it be better if it started loading as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0):

It will still work. This is more of a *best practice* than a technical requirement.

Comment: Yes but do you think that starting to load the async script in the head tagis a better practice than loading them near the end?If a script is big it could block loading of the page so it's better to load them at the bottom, but if everything is async maybe i should load everything as soon as possible.

Comment: Being synch would imply the page has ALREADY loaded.

Comment: Yes but i want them Async, becuase i'm making a widget and i'm bringing in my HTML/CSS/JS. So basically the script tags triggers a waterfall of async calls to load other things. If i start early and the page is heavy i might even finish bringing in my things before the page has even fully loaded if i start soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

The only things affecting the decision of where to put javascript are

- Dependencies / order of execution
- Loading time
- Best practice (which is largely due to load time)

It's advisable to load large chunks of javascript at the bottom of the page, for example jQuery, however if you load jQuery at the bottom of the page if you have any code with $ above the call to jQuery it will not work as $ has not been defined.
So in your case if it's only a small amount of code, it doesn't really matter so long as it's not being called before any dependencies.

Hope that helps.